# Org-mode archive entire file if all TODOs DONE

Tags: emacs, org-mode

While I've seen a lot of SO questions regarding archiving sub-trees, I use org-journal to create a daily file each day with a template (eg. `2018-09-14.org`) which then I then record todos in a pre-templated structure for personal, work or what have you which go through various states till they are either finished `DONE` or cancelled `KILL` (I find this approach works for me since it also allows me visually to see in the agenda view how long a task has been hanging around since started).

I am trying to write an interactive function which:

1. processes a list of all my .org agenda files, and
2. if it detects all `TODO`s and `DONE` or `KILL` in the file (or there are none present),
3. prompts me y, n, skip to move the entire file to its `whatever.org_archive`

(starting to see slowdowns with agenda builds 5 months into using org-mode).

I'm assuming someone else already uses a similar approach ('cause emacs) but was wondering if anyone could point me at a similar function or approach that would be helpful for sussing this out. Googling and thrashing on the elisp has been unproductive so far.

=== One month later === 
Well, teaching myself some lisp has helped but am now at the point where I have the 3 independent functions working, but for some reason am getting an error on calling the final function.

However, I'm getting an error on line 28 with invalid function: on the call to `rename-file-buffer-to-org-archive`. If someone can see what the problem is, this solves my use case (and probably someone else's which is why I pasted it back here.).

```
(defun archive-done-org-journal-files ()
"Cycles all org files through checking function."
(interactive) 
(save-excursion
(mapc 'check-org-file-finito (directory-files "~/Desktop/test_archives/" t ".org$"))
))

(defun check-org-file-finito (f)
"Checks TODO keyword items are DONE then archives."
(interactive)
(find-file f)
;; Shows open Todo items whether agenda or todo
(let (
  (kwd-re
    (cond (org-not-done-regexp)
      (
       (let ((kwd
          (completing-read "Keyword (or KWD1|KWD2|...): "
                 (mapcar #'list org-todo-keywords-1))))
       (concat "\\("
           (mapconcat 'identity (org-split-string kwd "|") "\\|")
           "\\)\\>")))
    ((<= (prefix-numeric-value) (length org-todo-keywords-1))
     (regexp-quote (nth (1- (prefix-numeric-value))
                org-todo-keywords-1)))
    (t (user-error "Invalid prefix argument: %s")))))
 (if (= (org-occur (concat "^" org-outline-regexp " *" kwd-re )) 0)
 ((rename-file-buffer-to-org-archive)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
   (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
   )))

(defun rename-file-buffer-to-org-archive ()
"Renames current buffer and file it's visiting."
(interactive)
(let ((name (buffer-name))
    (filename (buffer-file-name))
)
(if (not (and filename (file-exists-p filename)))
    (error "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" name)
  (let ((new-name (concat (file-name-sans-extension filename) ".org_archive")))
    (if (get-buffer new-name)
        (error "A buffer named '%s' already exists!" new-name)
      (rename-file filename new-name 1)
      (rename-buffer new-name)
      (set-visited-file-name new-name)
      (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
      (message "File '%s' successfully archived as '%s'."
               name (file-name-nondirectory new-name)))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, this is how I solved it. I'm sure there are optimizations and refactoring to be done here, but this definitely works and is reasonably modular if you need to figure it out. Just change the directory you use (mine is in Dropbox) for your org-files in the archive-done-org-journal-files and this should work for you. I highly recommend testing this on a test archive as per the `~/Desktop/test_archives/` directory as per the actual function just so you can make sure it works as advertised. YMMV. Hope it helps someone!

```
(defun archive-done-org-journal-files ()
"Cycles all org files through checking function."
(interactive) 
(save-excursion
(mapc 'check-org-file-finito (directory-files "~/Desktop/test_archives/" t ".org$"))
))

(defun check-org-file-finito (f)
"Checks TODO keyword items are DONE then archives."
(interactive)
(find-file f)
;; Shows open Todo items whether agenda or todo
(let (
(kwd-re
  (cond (org-not-done-regexp)
    (
     (let ((kwd
        (completing-read "Keyword (or KWD1|KWD2|...): "
                 (mapcar #'list org-todo-keywords-1))))
       (concat "\\("
           (mapconcat 'identity (org-split-string kwd "|") "\\|")
           "\\)\\>")))
    ((<= (prefix-numeric-value) (length org-todo-keywords-1))
     (regexp-quote (nth (1- (prefix-numeric-value))
                org-todo-keywords-1)))
    (t (user-error "Invalid prefix argument: %s")))))
 (if (= (org-occur (concat "^" org-outline-regexp " *" kwd-re )) 0)
 (rename-file-buffer-to-org-archive)
     (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
   )))

(defun rename-file-buffer-to-org-archive ()
"Renames current buffer and file it's visiting."
(interactive)
(let ((name (buffer-name))
    (filename (buffer-file-name))
)
(if (not (and filename (file-exists-p filename)))
    (error "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" name)
  (let ((new-name (concat (file-name-sans-extension filename) ".org_archive")))
    (if (get-buffer new-name)
        (error "A buffer named '%s' already exists!" new-name)
      (rename-file filename new-name 1)
      (rename-buffer new-name)
      (set-visited-file-name new-name)
      (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
  (message "File '%s' successfully archived as '%s'."
               name (file-name-nondirectory new-name)))))))
```